# Picasso and Glide not loading url

Tags: kotlin, android-studio, picasso, android-glide, resolve-url-loader

The code i have wrtitten is fine and i have checked everything including changing library versions , checking emulator internet , permissions and everything but still when i run the code i just see a blank page without picasso loading the url into imageview

[image: the code and the result]

i changed api levels and library versions and used other libraris but it just doesn't work

Comment: I checked the code related to Picasso and loading the picture. Everything works fine for me.
I think the problem is in the display of the imageView. Can you show your xml file?